# iOS - How to get notified when AFHTTPClient is done with all operations

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I use `AFHTTPClient` to upload files to an API as a `AFMultipartFormData`.
`AFHTTPRequestOperation`-s are created in a loop so I don't know how many they are or which one will be the last operation.

How can I get notified when `AFHTTPClient` is done with all operations?
there is `operationQueue` property which can count operations for me, but I don't want to add an observer for that..

Answer (score 1):

You could use GCD to put a block of code in the background that calls `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` on the queue and then sends out a notification.

Answer (score 1):

If @patric-schenke's answer doesn't work (for example, if you want to count only *upload* operations and not *all* operations, you can create a counter.  Create an `NSInteger`, and increment it when you add an operation.  Make sure to decrement it in both the success and failure blocks.

Why don't you want to add an observer to the `operationQueue`, though?  I think that'd get what you want with the least amount of code.

Comment: I agree with you that observer is the easiest way to implement it, but I think it will cause a little delay because observer has its own time interval and will not be fired right after the queue is done?

Comment: I use key-value observing on the operation queue in one of my apps, and it works great.  While it may be slower, the amount of time by which it is slower is imperceptible to a human.